# Super basic HTML/CSS formatting

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment while teaching myself to code.

```css
p.important {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<p class="important">Warning: We have no slow lorises here.</p>
```

This is supposed to change the font size to 150% and bold...but it's not working. Everything else in my code is running the way I want. But I can't get this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you specified your font-size in your body and html?  Set both body and html font-size to 100%.  Em's are relative off of the closest parent that has a font-size.  So setting body and HTML to have 100% font will set all fonts to 16px

Comment: Hi Kristi - your code is correct.  I've set up a jsfiddle for you: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt46w1mx/) - please note the code is working in the fiddle, so you may need to share more information with us (like the surrounding HTML / css)

Comment: @kristi Do you use Firebug?

Comment: @ntgCleaner note that setting to 100% doesn't guarantee 16px, although that is most common. That value is often set by the user's browser settings and can be changed.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan, You're right, it all depends on user and browser settings.  Either way, it sets a default font without zoom or accessibility to 16px on most browser/os combinations

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you performed a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: I had another issue today. The code doesn't run correctly in Brackets, but does run correctly in JS Fiddle. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

What is it showing? Your code looks correct. Is your style definition inside the head of the html? make sure it looks like this

```html
<head>
    <style>
        p.important {
          font-size: 1.5em;
          font-weight: 900;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="important">Warning: We have no slow lorises here.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the old practice. Now it doesn't have to be placed within `head`.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already - you probably need to specify your starting font-size.

When you start a new CSS, you should probably set your `body` and `html` to have `font-size:100%;`.  This will ensure that all of your text will be 16px starting off.  Then, when you want your text to be 32px, just set the element's font-size to 2em;

```
body, html {
    font-size:100%; //Sets default font size to 16px;
}
p.important {
    font-size:1.5em; //Is relative from the closest parent with a font-size 1.5*16 = 24px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight: bold;
```

You could try that. Remember, just calling the class `p.important` will not make it override an inherited class/id with a higher score.

You might try ...

```
p.important {
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
}
```

... to see if you can get it to work at all.